# Reduce the equation to a homogeneous equation by a change of variables

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

The equation is
$$
(x+1)^2 y'= (x+y)^2 -(y-1)(x+1)
$$
I've tried substituting for $z=x+y$, $z=x+1$, etc. but they don't seem to give me anything that's homogeneous after rearranging.

Comment: I looked at another example and tried X=x+1 and Y=y-1 which produces

y'=((X+Y)-(YX))/X^2

However I'm unsure if this is a valid method.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Try letting $z=x+1$ and $w=y-1$, so $x+y=z+w$.

After substituting, this should give $\displaystyle 
z^{2}\frac{dw}{dz}=(z+w)^2-wz.$

Comment: By doing this will y'(dy/dx) change to something else? If y=w-1, would y' -> w'+1?

Comment: @Alex: no ${}{}{}{}$ :)

Comment: @Alex Since $w=y-1$, $\frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}$ and $x=z-1\implies\frac{dx}{dz}=1\implies\frac{dw}{dz}=\frac{dw}{dx}\cdot\frac{dx}{dz}=\frac{dw}{dx}=\frac{dy}{dx}$.

Comment: So essentially

$$
(dy/dx)=((z+w)-wz)/z^2


 ( dy(z))/( dz) = (w (-z)+w+z)/z^2:
 
y(z)  =   integral (w+z-w z)/z^2 dz  =  -w/z+(-w+1) log(z)+c_1

$$

And then substitute back? Seems like I'm overlooking something.